# capistrano deployment no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

Here is my deploy.rb file

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-2.0.0-p247"
set :rvm_type, :user

set :application, "myproject"
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git"
set :user, "server-login-name"
set :branch, "master"
set :stages, %w{staging production}
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :use_sudo, true
set :rvm_install_with_sudo, true

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :port, 2021

set :scm, :git

role :web, "mydomain.com"
role :app, "mydomain.com"
role :db,  "mydomain.com", :primary => true
role :db,  "mydomain.com"

after "deploy:update_code","deploy:config_symlink"

set :rvm_type, :system

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    #run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  task :config_symlink do
    #run "cp #{release_path}/config/database.yml.example #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end

before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby'
before 'deploy', 'rvm:create_gemset'
```

My staging.rb and production.rb has the following in separate file

```
set :deploy_to, "/var/rails_apps/project_stage"
set :deploy_to, "/var/rails_apps/project"
```

Now I am facing two error

```
1. triggering before callbacks for `deploy'
the task `rvm:install_ruby' does not exist
```

If i comment `rvm:install_ruby` and `rvm:create_gemset`

```
2. cannot open: no such file or directory for all my file and folders
```

I could not find why this is happening. can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

RVM:install_ruby isn't a thing in capistrano-RVM?

Comment: I can't get you. What do you mean?

Comment: The tasks you mention in the 1. Question simply don't exist. They are not a feature of the gem you are using.